# cakephp 3 displaying date without time

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP 3: I have a database field which is a DATE (not DATETIME nor TIMESTAMP)

When I display

```
echo $contact->date;
```

It will show something like **2014. 01. 06. 0:00**. How to hide hours and minutes?

I tried

```
print $this->Time->format($contact->date, 'Y-m-d');
```

but I got **2014-0-6**

How to get year-month-day?

rrd

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
echo $contact->date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Actually it answers the question. This is the right solution.

Comment: For reference: **[TimeHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/time.html)** | **[Time](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html)**

Comment: You could use 
    echo $contact->date->toFormattedDateString()

Answer (score 5):

add in App\Controller:

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;
Time::$defaultLocale = 'es-ES';
Time::setToStringFormat('YYYY-MM-dd');
```

Comment: If you don't want to override defaults and want to use localized formatting, you can use something like  `$this->Time->i18nFormat($contact->date, [IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE])` or other formatting options from [PHP's IntlDateFormatter class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)

Comment: Kari's comment should be the accepted answer because all the other answers hard-code to a certain format that will not be adjusted if the local were to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly print the date object in any custom date String format by using the inbuilt  **i18nFormat** function.

```
$frozenDateObj->i18nFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy');
```

Use [Datetime Format Syntax](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#date-field-symbol-table) reference for more customization

Answer (score 1):

```
use Cake\I18n\FrozenTime;

$time =new FrozenTime('2021-01-31 22:11:30');
$timex =  $time->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
echo $timex;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If need all over the project with specific format you can use
boostrap.php

```
Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: not sure about this answer. When I tried Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat returns void. which is not helpful in above question.

Comment: @Invincible may be you miss something, please check in official document [Setting the Default Locale and Format String](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#setting-the-default-locale-and-format-string)

Answer (score 0):

echo date_format($contact->date, 'Y-m-d'); //php format

Answer (score -1):

try

date('Y-m-d',strtotime($contact->date));