# CakePHP 3 - Displaying time without date

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP 3.

I have a database field which is DATETIME. What I want is to show the time without the date.

**Example:**

Field value: 2015-09-08 07:27:12.000000

What I want to show: 7:27 AM

**I tried:**

```
<?= $event->date->format('HH:mm') ?>
```

I got **07:09** (Hour-Month).

**OR**

```
<?= $this->Time->format($event->date, [null, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT]) ?>
```

I got **Tuesday, September 8, 2015 at 7:27 AM**.

I would like to know how to get **Hours-Minutes AM/PM**.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561226/cakephp-3-displaying-date-without-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is not an acceptable formatting style, instead use `\IntlDateFormatter::NONE` to suppress parts of the date.

```
$this->Time->format($event->date, [\IntlDateFormatter::NONE, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT]);
```

or

```
$event->date->i18nFormat([\IntlDateFormatter::NONE, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT]);
```

Given that your application uses a suitable locale (like `en_US`), this should leave you with your desired time format.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html) it should be:

```
$event->date->format('h:i A');
```

Where `i` is the minutes and `A` is `AM` or `PM`. This is using PHP's date's format, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for additional usages/formats.